# What is the network connection speed between two containers communicating via a virtual bridge running on the same host?

Tags: virtualization, linux-networking, docker, lxc

Does a virtual bridge (added to /etc/network/interfaces) limit the transfer speed of data from the memory of one lxc/docker container to another?

For example does the memory throughput drop to that of 1G/10G Ethernet or is there no significant difference? That is, would the throughput between two processes running on the same machine be almost identical to the two processes running on individual lxc containers on the same host?